# Error: INSERT INTO users

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to enter form data in MySQL database. I am getting the below error:

```
Error: INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, password,full_address,city,age,contact_number,gender,education,profile_picture) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Code

```
<?php 
 $full_name = $_POST["fullname"]; 
 $email = $_POST["email"]; 
 $password = $_POST["password"]; 
 $full_address = $_POST["address"]; 
 $city = $_POST["city"]; 
 $age = $_POST["age"]; 
 $contact_number = $_POST["number"]; 
 $gender = $_POST["gender"]; 
 $education = $_POST["education"]; 

?>

<?php
$servername = "hidden";
$username = "hidden";
$db_password = "hidden";
$dbname = "hidden";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $db_password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){ $errors= array(); 
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name']; 
$file_size =$_FILES['image']['size']; 
$file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
$file_type=$_FILES['image']['type']; 
$extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
$new= rand(0000,9999); 
$file_name=$new.'.'.$extension; 
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name); 
echo "Success"; 
} 
     //  if(isset($_FILES['image'])){ $errors= array(); $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name']; $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size']; $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type']; $extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); $new= rand(0000,9999); $file_name=$new.'.'.$extension; move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name); echo "Success"; } 

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, password,full_address,city,age,contact_number,gender,education,profile_picture)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);

// Bind parameters
$stmt->bind_param("s", $full_name);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $password);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $full_address);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $age);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $contact_number);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $gender);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $education);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $file_name);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

/*

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, password,full_address,city,age,contact_number,gender,education)
VALUES ('$full_name', '$email', '$password','$full_address','$city','$age','$contact_number','$gender','$education')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
*/
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $full_name);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $password);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $full_address);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $age);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $contact_number);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $gender);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $education);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $file_name);
```

with

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $full_name, $email, $password, $full_address, $city, $age, $contact_number, $gender, $education, $file_name);
```

Make sure that you validate and sanitize `$_POST`.